# Customize JAXB behaviour with Apache CXF

Tags: xml, soap, cxf, jax-ws, jaxb2

We are using Apache CXF for a Java first soap based webservice implementation as opposed to contract first approach. We also haven't specified any data binding which would potentially mean that the default JAXB Databinding would be used.

From a memory profiling recently, we found that there were millions of duplicate String objects created. I would like to avoid this by potentially trying to call String's intern() method. If I were not using CXF, I know we could have done this by returning String.intern() from https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseString%28java.lang.String%29  and specifying an external jaxb binding file in the classpath.For e.g. something like this -

```
public static String forceStringInterning(String str) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(str)) {
        return null;
    }
    return DatatypeConverter.parseString(str).intern();
}
```

However, this didn't work with CXF.

On reading from the CXF website, I understand that CXF internally uses JAXBDataBinding.java which exposes certain properties and some other maps (marshaller, unmarshaller, contextProperties etc.) but, I wasn't able to find a way to proceed any further with what I aim to achieve.

The other option would have been to use an XMLJavaTypeAdapter for String that forces intern but, even that would have meant that I would have to create a package-info.java for each package and subpackage where I want this behaviour.

I have looked at other examples where people seem to have tried other customization approaches for e.g. [Reuse CXF jaxb context between multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687528/reuse-cxf-jaxb-context-between-multiple-services) but, haven't managed to solve it yet.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: For now, I did use XMLJavaTypeAdapter to force this behaviour and created package-info.java for each package but, I still think there could be a better solution possibly.