# Apache CXF JAX-WS spring-boot starter very slow

Tags: performance, spring-boot, cxf, jax-ws

I'm working on a `spring-boot` application which has `100+ JAX-WS endpoints`. I'm using apache CXF and the boot time performance is terrible. It takes more than 10 mins to publish 100 endpoints.

I tried to enable debug logs and see that cxf is creating a new `JAXBContext` instance for every endpoint. I tried to find material to configure single `JAXBContext` but none of the available material show properly how I can do it.

> FYI: I'm using JavaFirst approach here.

Any suggestions to improve boot time performance are welcome.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

For JAX-WS please look at this existing question: [Reuse CXF jaxb context between multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687528/reuse-cxf-jaxb-context-between-multiple-services)

Instead of declaring it using XML you can also add the bean for `org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding` using the `@Bean` annotation.

In case someone is looking for JAX-RS, this is handled differently. You need to add a bean for `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider` and set `singleJaxbContext` to `true` as written in the docs: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-SingleJAXBContextandextrauserclasses

Comment: This works for REST(JAXRS) services but for SOAP(JAXWS) is there a simple way like this to do it ?

Comment: My bad, just changed the answer and added a link for JAX-WS. Please let me know if you have further questions...

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to configure single instance of JAXBContext by extending JAXBDatabinding class like it was suggested by Anver Levy in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687528/reuse-cxf-jaxb-context-between-multiple-services. but every second request onwards the mapping seems to get messed up for all the SOAP requests! All my 1st SOAP requests are successful but from 2nd onwards I get argument mismatch exception.